# Using a un-named objects

Tags: java, oop

I'm learning Java and have the following question related to using objects in a List.

I have created a class called `User`.

This class uses a constructor which takes two strings when creating a new object:

`String username, String password`

I'm practicing creating Lists of User objects from the user class and have written the following:

```
    public void createAndManipulateListOfUsers(){

    List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();

    userList.add(new User("user1","password1"));
    userList.add(new User("user2","password2"));
```

Now lets say I wanted to find the index position of one of these user objects using the `indexOf` method how would I do this since I've not named the objects?

I've approached the same situation in a slightly different way, creating and naming each object before adding them to the list, like this:

```
    List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();

    User bob = new User("user1","password1");
    User jim = new User("user2","password2");

    userlist.add(bob);
    userlist.add(jim);

    /* because i've given each object a name on creation 
    i am able to use the objects like this:*/

    System.out.println(userList.indexOf(bob));
    assertEquals(0,userList.indexOf(bob));
```

So is there a way that I can identify the `User` objects created in my first example in order to return the index positions using the `indexOf` method?

Comment: The `indexOf` method accepts an object: you need to construct another object with the required properties (i.e. `userlist.indexOf(new User("user1", "password1"))`) and implement the `equals` method in the `User` class.

Comment: It is not "naming an object". `User bob = ...` is just a reference which points to some object in the memory.

Comment: Thanks Jaroslaw,

Answer (score 0):

The trick is that `indexOf` loop over your `List` and uses `equals` at each turn.

If you want it to recognize that the user inside your `List`, you have to tell java how to tell if the needle user is the same than the user in the list, by overriding the `equals` method from `Object`.

Please note that this is for educationnal purpose, for most case you should create a reference, just like in your second sample.

You can try this on [compilejava](https://www.compilejava.net/) :

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.List; 

// one class needs to have a main() method
public class HelloWorld
{
  // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();

    userList.add(new User("user1","password1"));
    userList.add(new User("user2","password2"));

    User needle = new User("user2","password2");
    System.out.println(userList);
    System.out.println(userList.indexOf(needle));
  }
}

// you can add other public classes to this editor in any order
public class User
{
  private String a;
  private String b;
  public User(String a, String b)  {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object other){
    User otheruser = (User)other;
    return (this.a.equals(otheruser.a) && this.b.equals(otheruser.b));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you want to identify your object (`User` instance). The example you've given (that you call "naming them") identifies the object by their reference (~ address in memory). What you actually did was store this reference to a named variable then used it to identify the `User` instance.

Other possible ways to identify the user are:

- Add an `equals()` method to express that two `User` instances describe in fact the same user if some (or all) of their fields are equal; then query using a new `User` instance with same relevant fields
- Use a `Map<KEY, User>` rather than `List<User>` to store and retrieve the users by some identifier - `KEY` being whichever type suits your need as a key type (e.g. `String`).

Comment: Thanks Jiri. i guess "referencing" was the correct terminology i should have used instead of naming :)